# Resharper 2019.1.1 in combination Visual Studio 2019 (16.1) slow

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2019

A new year, new releases, and like always new aggrevation. The combination of Visual Studio 2019 (16.1 release) and Resharper 2019.1.1 is deadly for our not so large solution (10 projects & 6 test projects) in 1 solution .NET Core 2.2. Not combined with frontend (javascript/typescript).

When opening solution, VS hangs and uses A LOT of CPU, and it now even has come to a point that i need to disable resharper to continue developing.
And not only disabling resharper, i also needed to disable code lens in Visual Studio, because ServiceHub.RoslynCodeAnalysis service was still taking a lot of CPU, found that on (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/19205)

I already found this article on Jetbrains site: https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206546919 , but this time i can't figure out what the problem is.

I also found this on microsoft developer community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/521943/vs-2019-high-cpu-and-memory-usage.html : 
***status 01/06/2019 - NO SOLUTION***

I also created my own ticket on the developer community, will keep both sites in sync: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/593963/visual-studio-2019-version-161-slow-and-consuming.html
***status 04/06/2019 - TICKET CREATED***

Anybody in the community with the same issue and some help on how to solve it.

It's not hardware related ot OS related, probably some settings from both systems that mess up each other.

For more detail:

- Visual Studio: ***default*** installation
- Resharper: ***default*** installation
- Codebase: rather small: a few hundred tests / a few hundred classes
- Hardware: Parallels on MAC: with 10GB RAM; 8 CPU machine (been doing
  that for years, i am only having problems since upgrading to 2019
  versions)
- ***No frontend projects*** included
- Only API in .NET Core 2.2
- No continuous testing
- ***Solution wide analysis off*** resharper disabled
- ***No fancy plugins, no custom rules, no metrics*** (all that is done on Azure Devops when code is being build ETC

> > > > >

**Update: 25 June 2019** (and it is running again at a usable speed)

No info on ticket from Microsoft website

- Executed these things
- Visual Studio 16.1.3 update Reshaper 2019.1.2
  update
- Codelens disabled
- Disabled defender for these processes *(be aware about what you do, no scanning will happen in these processed)*:
  [image: processed excluded from defender]
- Code.exe & Node.exe: we have an angular frontend ConEmu64.exe &
- conhost.exe & dotnet.exe : we have .net core api running in kestrel
- sqlserv.exe: we have a sql backend  Also excluded my sourcefolder
  from defender

Many thanks

Comment: What did you activate in Resharper? What in Visual Studio? How large are the projects? How many Unit Tests? Any Integration testing as Unit test?. Please provide more Information regarding the settings and/or your hardware because right now it could be anything (e.g. you have 12000 Unit Tests in your six projects and you have continous testing on every change in Resharper and VS activated)

Comment: according to these numbers, very small project, a few hundred tests , a few hundred classes

Comment: Is anything like continous testing or any Code metrics running? Is Resharper doing a Code Analysis on Startup that could slow down your starting experience? Do you have any heavy custom rule sets that you need to follow?

Comment: Try deactivating everything (I know it is quite a lot) regarding Resharper and start flipping it on again until you encounter your problems again. Then you have your culprit. If that doesn't work repeat the same with the Visual Studio stuff.

Comment: @Brezelmann, thx, i am doing this in parallel, when i have more insights, i'll update this question, thx for the tips

Comment: It may just be VS2019 being slow. We have slow PCs at work and the newer VS Editions are painfully slow, especially with bigger or multiple projects, so we're mostly staying at VS2015.

Comment: @Patrick, thx, i have some more info, after disabling resharper and code lens in VS 2019 still no improvement. I've now loaded the solution in VS2017 with resharper enabled, and that is a lot better